# Move multiple apps to SD card

Tags: external-sd, app2sd

Is there an app or a way to transfer multiple apps to the SD card? It's slow and tedious to just use the "move" button in the app settings.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use two related apps which were quite helpful.

- [SDMove](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beaglebros.SDMove) - Lists all currently installed applications which can be moved to the SD card and facilitates doing so.
- [SDWatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beaglebros.SDWatch), which runs in the background and watches for app installations. When it sees one, and the app can be moved to the SD card, it gives you a notification which takes you to the settings for the app so that you can move it.

You'll still need to move each one one at a time, but SDMove does reduce the number of taps required.

There are other, similar, apps in the Play Store.

Comment: The above app links are dead

Comment: These apps don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

A late post but I think [AppMgr III](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd)
can help.
In order to move apps directly you must have a pro version of it . Although the free version is not that bad. It shows you the apps that can be moved, along with the consequences (like unavailability of widgets, etc). It also reduces the need of some extra clicks for moving apps to SD, so I think it's cool, though not the best.